# Best way for generating consecutive unique values

Tags: php, mysql

What is the best way to generate consecutive values when you have a load balanced database and instances of your application ?

For example, i have a load balanced mysql database.
My PHP application, is deployed with docker and has 3 containers

I have to generate consecutive ids. I cannot use auto increment because i have to generate unique ids depending on relations (For example, i have to generate a unique bill number depending on witch society it is related)

My bill can be generated but not emmited. I must generate the unique value when the bill is emitted.

TRIGGER ON UPDATE is the good solution or not ?

Thnks for your answers

Comment: "i have to generate a unique bill number depending on witch society it is related". This is a bad requirement IMO. The bill number should just be a number. Other metadata can hold information about which customer it relates to. And what do you mean by "emitted" - do you mean when it is sent to the customer? Why must you wait till then to generate a number? Is there some genuine business reason for it?

Comment: The requirement is bad, but it is qhat the client wants and it permits to sort the files. A bill can be generated and not immediatly validated because user can modify its content. When the bill is validated, the bill is valid and "emitted". At this moment, i have to generate my ID because if the bill is cancel and not emitted, i must not have a hole in my list of generated IDs.

Comment: "but it is qhat the client wants" you don't necessarily have to do everything the client wants exactly, if you can justify to them that it's not a good idea, and you have a better one which will still enable them to do business efficiently (maybe even more efficiently - e.g. without technical problems!). If you make a clear and reasonable case then you should be able to get an agreement, or at least a compromise. They are not the IT expert...you are. If there is a technical difficulty with the requirement, which there is in this case, you should say so.

Comment: "i must not have a hole in my list of generated IDs" - who cares? It's just a number. It's a unique identifier for the record, that's its only job. Don't use it to, for example, count how many bills there are for a given client or something - that's what SQL COUNT() is for. Again if your client is asking for this, just gently explain to them why you're not going to do it like that, because it creates technical difficulties and is unnecessary - there are other ways to convey the information that the bill number is trying to represent, and you will provide them.

Comment: BTW I have seen billing systems where the bill initially is in "draft" state, and has a unique "draft ID" generated by the database. Then when it's confirmed and released to the customer, a row in a different table is generated with the final, unalterable details and this is given a final "bill ID", again generated by the database. Then the draft and bill are linked together by a key relationship in the DB. So that's one option for you to get round that situation. Again, it's just an auto-generated number, no messing about trying to create pointless artificial sequences etc.

Comment: "you don't necessarily have to do everything the client wants exactly, if you can justify to them that it's not a good idea" : here, i am just trying to expose a problem without explaining all the systems existing around. The client requirement is good. There is Electronic Document Management and other applications working with my application. And yes, i must not have a hole in my list of generated IDs because, legaly this is a requirement (https://www.service-public.fr/professionnels-entreprises/vosdroits/F23208).

Answer (score 0):

I would save the current id in a db table.
Each time you want to increase the id, do the following:

- Start a transaction
- Block the id row in the db table: in mysql use FOR UPDATE
- Read the current id
- increase the id
- generate the bill with the id
- Store the id back to the db
- Commit the transaction

Answer (score -2):

I'd go for MAX(id)+1
You can get the next number in the sequence with a query like:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id),0) + 1 FROM bill
 WHERE society = 'XYZ'
```

You'll have to take steps to ensure that two processes don't generate the same number and that can be complicated but not insurmountable.

Personally, I would always avoid a trigger. I've never used trigger and not regretted it later.